# Concrete slabs and block paving - painting

Tags: painting, driveway, landscaping

I have concrete block paving and concrete slabs that I would like to paint to reuse, renovate, rejuvenate.  Any suggestions whether painting would do the trick?  The block paving is in the driveway taking a car, slabs are for foot traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Inside, the painting would work & should last 10-years before needing to be scraped of bubbles, peels & cracks before a repainting. But, down the long road it'll need to be completely stripped off & re-done, which is a huge pain. But outdoors, no, I haven't seen a paint or paint re-surfacer last very long at all & they fail miserably.

You'd probably be much better off [**with something like this**](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Eagle-1-gal-Rustic-Concrete-Acid-Stain-EDADR/203012900) that actually soaks into the surface to become part of the surface. Scroll down to just above Reviews & to the right side in order to check out the numerous real world pictures.

The garage floor & its driveway apron I did at my old place came out like veiny leather & looked amazing. The real benefit is you just keep re-applying clear sealer, every 5 or more years for me (I only did an early 2nd time for re-sale), so there's no color matching & the stain beneath doesn't lighten nor deteriorate.

Comment: I have used acid stain on new cement patio's with really good results but on older stained areas with car traffic I have had better luck with 2 part epoxy paint.  The epoxy paint will hold up a little better to car traffic. If you decide on epoxy paint make sure it is the 2 part made for outdoor / garage use. The indoor stuff peals did not hold up well under the tire path area. Prior to painting a acid etch is needed. My shop has 3 bays that were done on 04 still look great even out on the outside apron. I think the sealer on acid stain will need to be done every couple of years with cars.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big fan on the single can paints. Like you, I've seen the "claims" fall very short of the mark. I haven't used a 2-part epoxy though & your situation sounds great, that's a nice long time. In my case the 2 garage bays were separated so it was very easy to just plop down another sealer coat. But, after 5-years, inside & out, there was only a very slight difference where the tires traveled, virtually unnoticeable.

Comment: was this a new garage?  I have had some minor problems with old rust stains showing on a patio with acid stain but it still looked 10000% better and way more color choices.+

Comment: Actually, 1 was 1-year old, a massive air compressor's weight broke up the 1-inch thick slab pretty bad. And the other was 80-years old & after an incredible amount of scraping, scrubbing & oven cleaner it came out almost identical to the new slab. Of course, there were veining differences, but you'd be hard pressed to tell which was which.

Comment: After, iggys response it may be cheaper and look better than epoxy paint.+ to iggy